# Submatrix summation doesn't work for NumericMatrix Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I observed the following weird situation when defining an Rcpp function.

The first function works perfectly, and calculates the sum of submatrix `s`

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]

double Sub(NumericMatrix m){
  NumericMatrix s = m(Range(0,0),Range(0,1));
  return sum(s);
}
```

However, when I alternate the code in the following way

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double Sub(NumericMatrix m){
  return sum(m(Range(0,0),Range(0,1)));
}
```

It doesn't work which is really counterintuitive. The error that I get is the following `no matching function for call to 'sum(Rcpp::Matrix<14>::Sub)'`

I just skip a step, where I define the submatrix `NumericMatrix s`.

A matrix that can be used to check that is the following

```
 n = matrix(c(6090,16,0,0,618,1036,3,0,99,0,312,4,25,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,1794,0,0,0,0),5,5,byrow=TRUE)
 n
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] 6090   16    0    0  618
[2,] 1036    3    0   99    0
[3,]  312    4   25    0    0
[4,]    3    0    0    0    0
[5,] 1794    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: The Template Metaprogramming permitting such expressions is hard, specifically with the added return-to-R conversion.  If it fails, use two steps.  We have recommended that very approach in many answers here before.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Okok I see. So, I assume in time comparison is better to use ```arma::mat```to avoid reassignments.

Comment: Not what I said, and not what matters: the key is `return` expressions are difficult. Also, `sum()` and `Range()` and both from the `Rcpp::` namespace.  As you seem to think it's `arma::`, I would recommend writing everything explicitly (as many folks, myself included, do in package code).  What you have, unless I miss something, is a 100% Rcpp example and the include for RcppArmadillo, in the example above, is pointless.  Now, operating on submatrices is very powerful in Armadillo but that is not what you used here.